# Reducing verbosity of states in flutter_bloc library

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

I'm implementing a simple chat screen that lists messages and has a textbox and button to send.

I have the following states:

```
abstract class ChatState extends Equatable {
  const ChatState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ChatFailure extends ChatState {
  final Exception reason;
  const ChatFailure({this.reason});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [reason];
}

class ChatInProgress extends ChatState {}

class ChatSuccess extends ChatState {
  final Chat chat;
  final List<Message> messages;
  final Map<int, User> users;

  const ChatSuccess({
    @required this.chat,
    @required this.messages,
    @required this.users,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [chat, messages, users];
}
```

However, I now want to be able to show the messages in all the states (if not null), even error or loading states - it might be displaying a cache.

It seems I have two ways to do this, but neither seem like a good option:

1. Make `ChatState` the only state, and shove everything in there. Seems like an anti-pattern.
2. Put `chat`, `messages` and `users` in `ChatState` so all the states have them. However, then every state has a huge long constructor and it's really verbose, especially as this screen will become more complex.

I'm going with 2 for now, but is that really the best way? Am I using `bloc_library` in the correct way?

Comment: why would you want to display messages in loading state? Could you explain the business logic a bit more so we can come up with a correct solution?

Comment: @Limbou say for example, there is a stale cached version of the variables, or perhaps the user has done a 'pull to refresh'. It's a better user experience to still display the old data with a spinner while the new data is loading (instead of just a spinner and a blank screen or skeleton).

Comment: I think in that case it would be better to actually add `showLoading` boolean to `ChatSuccess` state

Comment: Do you mean, keep the other states for when there is no data to display, and when data is refreshed it goes `ChatSuccess(old data) -> ChatSuccess(oldData, loading) -> ChatSuccess(newData)`?

Comment: exactly, something like that. You would definitely have two loading states here: One if there is no data to display (just a loading indicator), and other if you have some data already, but want to refresh it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the suggestion from post comment seems reasonable, I'm moving it here:

If we consider the following business logic in steps:

1. User enters a screen, he sees the loading indicator (data loads here)
2. If there was no error, he now sees a view with all the data fetched earlier
3. He can press a button/pull to refresh the data

In that case I would suggest adding a `showLoading` boolean to `ChatSuccess` state. This way you display data and also a spinning indicator at the same time.

The flow with the states would be following:

```
ChatInProgress -> ChatSuccess(firstData, showLoading: false) -> (pull to refresh) -> ChatSuccess(firstData, showLoading: true) -> ChatSuccess(secondData, showLoading: false)
```